# How to label extracted peak values in time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series, label

I am a noob at R, but I am working with a ton of time series data of neuronal recordings in vivo.

I am able to plot the time series, and extract local maxima using a custom find_peaks function I found online (from the fluoR package):

```
df <- format_data(GCaMP)
head(df)

pks <- find_peaks(xvals = df$Trial8,
              n.points = 10) 

neg_pks <- find_peaks(xvals = df$Trial8,
                  n.points = -10) 

## line plot of data

ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Time, y = Trial8))
```

So after this I have a dataframe with my data, and separate 'values' labeled neg_pks and pks, which identify which points in the data are positive or negative peaks. How can I then map this onto my line graph to create something like this?:

[image: Labeled Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how the geom functions typically also accept a data argument. Meaning you can easily add a geom_point layer that plots other data (the subset you have found)

So something like this: (untested)

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Time, y=Trial8) ) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point( data=df[ pks, ], col="red" ) +
    geom_point( data=df[ neg_pks, ], col="red" ) # or perhaps another color?
```

Comment: awesome, this works like a charm! ...I'm still barely getting started with ggplot...thanks!